# Export a row from php table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I try to export a single row as CSV but instead, my code fetches all the rows.

Here is my screenshot:[image: export]
Here is my code: 
index.php

```
<?php
    db();
    global $link;

    $query  = "SELECT id, name, address, contact, age, birthday FROM info";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id           = $row['id'];
        $name          = $row['name'];
        $address       = $row['address'];
        $contact       = $row['contact'];
        $age           = $row['age'];
        $birthday      = $row['birthday'];
        ?>

        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['birthday']; ?></td>
           <td><a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $id?>">View</a></td>
           <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>">Update</a></td>
           <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" onClick="return confirm('Delete This account?')">Delete</a></td>
           <td>    
            <form method="post" action="export_excel.php" id="export_sql"> 
                <input type="submit" name="export" value="EXCEL"> 
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
         <form method="post" action="export_pdf.php"  id="export_pdf" target="_blank">
            <input type="submit" name="export_pdf" value="PDF">
        </form> 
    </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

export_sql.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["export"])) {
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bondad-crud") ;
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    fputcsv($output, array('id','name','address','contact','age','birthday', 'date'));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}


?>
```

I tried to fetch the row by id but still got an error.

Comment: enable error reporting and show what error you are getting?

Comment: You do not pass the the `id` of the row to the export php.

Comment: Here is the error:

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bondad-crud\export_excel.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />

Comment: As I wrote above, you do not pass the `id` of the row over to the export php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The main problem is that your are adding a new form for each iteration of your while loop. This will cause the type of problems you are having.  I have removed the `<form>` tags from the inside of the loop to the outside of the loop.

Your second problem is that your ID is not correctly being passed to your export page(s).

I changed the names of your two submit buttons so that they will be represented by an array in your post data.  The key of the first element in the array will be the id.

```
db();
  global $link;

  $query  = "SELECT id, name, address, contact, age, birthday FROM info";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  echo 
  '<form method="post" action="export_excel.php" id="export_sql">';

  echo 
  '<table>';

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $id         = $row['id'];
    $name       = $row['name'];
    $address    = $row['address'];
    $contact    = $row['contact'];
    $age        = $row['age'];
    $birthday   = $row['birthday'];

       echo
       '<tr>' .
          '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>' .
          '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>' .
          '<td>' . $row['address'] . '</td>' .
          '<td>' . $row['contact'] . '</td>' .
          '<td>' . $row['age'] . '</td>' .
          '<td>' . $row['birthday'] . '</td>' . 
          '<td><a href="read.php?id=<' . $id . '">View</a></td>' .
          '<td><a href="update.php?id=<' . $id . '">Update</a></td>' .
          '<td><a href="delete.php?id=<' . $id . '" onClick="return confirm("Delete This account?")">Delete</a></td>' .
          '<td><input type="submit" name="export[' . $id . ']" value="EXCEL">' . '</td>' .
          '<td><input type="submit" name="export_pdf[' . $id . ']" value="PDF"></td>' . 
        '</tr>';

}

  echo
  '</table>';

echo
'</form>';
```

Notice that you only have one form now.

For your `export_sql.php page`:

We will grab the first key of the `$_POST[export]` array or the `$_POST[export_pdf]` and that will be you ID.  Now we have an ID to pass  to the correct query.

Note that you can now handle both the Excel and the PDF download from this page.

```
<?php
//Do code for Excels
if (isset($_POST["export"])) {
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bondad-crud") ;
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    fputcsv($output, array('id','name','address','contact','age','birthday', 'date'));

    reset($_POST["export"]); //Added this.
    $id = key($_POST["export"]); //And this.

    $query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}

//Handle the PDF's.
if (isset($_POST["export_pdf"])) {

  reset($_POST["export_pdf"]); //Added this.
  $id = key($_POST["export_pdf"]); //And this.

  //.....Do the rest of code for the PDF's

}

?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, this does not provide a solution to the above question.

Comment: @Shadow It certainly helps.  He is looping his forms out.

Comment: His next problem will be getting the right ID to download.

Comment: @Joseph_J thanks for your response but, i've got a Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\bondad-crud\index.php on line 73

Comment: Good, I'm glad it worked out for you!  Best of luck on the rest of your project. ~Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you shall need to learn [PHP Form Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

You need to pass the id on both pages.

You need pass id with hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">` on index.php

```
<?php
    db();
    global $link;

    $query  = "SELECT id, name, address, contact, age, birthday FROM info";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id           = $row['id'];
        $name          = $row['name'];
        $address       = $row['address'];
        $contact       = $row['contact'];
        $age           = $row['age'];
        $birthday      = $row['birthday'];
        ?>

        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['birthday']; ?></td>
           <td><a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $id?>">View</a></td>
           <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>">Update</a></td>
           <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" onClick="return confirm('Delete This account?')">Delete</a></td>
           <td>    
            <form method="post" action="export_excel.php" id="export_sql"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="export" value="EXCEL"> 
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
         <form method="post" action="export_pdf.php"  id="export_pdf" target="_blank">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="export_pdf" value="PDF">
        </form> 
    </td>
        <td>
         <form method="post" action="export_sql.php"  id="export_pdf" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="export_sql" value="PDF">
        </form> 
    </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

and you need proccess the id sent by index.php using $_POST like `$id = $_POST["id"];` on export_sql.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["export"])) {
 $id = $_POST["id"];
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bondad-crud") ;
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    fputcsv($output, array('id','name','address','contact','age','birthday', 'date'));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}


?>
```

Comment: Hey sir thank you for your response but I've got a <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bondad-crud\export_excel.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />

Comment: @JohnMarkBondad did you add `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">` as i wrote  on above answer in the form?

Comment: should be 
  `<form method="post" action="export_excel.php" id="export_sql"> 
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="export" value="EXCEL"> 
            </form>`